# How to vertically center two strings?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 strings next to each other. The second string is set to be `font-size: 85%`. This is the ugly result depicted in the screenshot below. How can I make the align the second string so that is vertically centered relative to the first string?

```
.smaller_text {
  font-size: 85%;
}

some bigger text&#160;
<span class="smaller_text"> some smaller text&#160;</span>
```

[image]

Comment: You must use `line-height`

Comment: Is there a safe way to use line-height when I'm not explicitly setting a font-size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting line heights and vertical alignment you can get what you're after:

```
.smaller_text {
    ...
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/Le7nruep/)**

Comment: Is there a smart/safe value to set line-height to if I'm not explicitly setting a font-size?

Comment: You don't have to use line-height. I did it in the demo because it takes out some of the space left for descenders under the text, making "middle" more in the middle. You'll need to use some explicit formatting structure to get pixel-perfect centering.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite:

```css
body {
    font-size: 24px;
}
.liner {
    position: relative;
}

.smaller_text {
  font-size: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: auto;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="liner">
some bigger text
<span class="smaller_text"> some smaller text&#160;</span>
</div>
```